# How do I copy statusbar text that appears when hovering a link?

Tags: firefox, clipboard, links

For example, on [this page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/liveboot-t2976189), the status bar and `href` parameter of the link is:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.liveboot
```

But the text copies when I do "Copy Link Location" is like this:

```
http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_142413366979510&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=11cc1952-fa65-4ea2-bbcf-bbe1319ebe93&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fandroid%2Fapps-games%2Fliveboot-t2976189&v=1&out=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Deu.chainfire.liveboot&title=%5BAPP%5D%5B4.3%2B%5D%5BROOT%5D%5B2014.01.03%5D%20LiveBoot%20(Logc%E2%80%A6%20%7C%20Android%20Development%20and%20Hacking%20%7C%20XDA%20Forums&txt=Google%20Play
```

How do I copy status bar's or hover's text without using "View Source" and other debugging features?

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable JavaScript on the page (various browsers have various ways for that).
2. Copy the link as you did before.
3. (Re-enable JavaScript if needed.)

Tested with Opera browser, where I disabled JS in options. Other browsers may have plugins controllable by one click to enable/disable JS directly from toolbar.

I doubt there is other way (maybe except some special plugins) because example link you posted is designed to work in that JS-enhanced way so every standard-compliant browser will change it in way as you shown in your question. It is expected behavior. Way I've shown you is straightforward, it directly addresses the engine responsible for modifying the link. :)

Answer (score 0):

With this add-on I have no more problems with those "redirects" of URLs, I always have access to the real URL:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/redirectbypasser/?src=ss

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself.